# How to add/check policy and role .net core API securing with Identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, roles, policy

I have a doubt on API securing with identity server4

**IdentityResource**

| Name | Claims |
| --- | --- |
| Roles | role |

**APIResource**

| Name | Scopes |
| --- | --- |
| testapi | api1 |

**APIScopes**

| Name | Claims |
| --- | --- |
| api1 | address |

**In Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = "testapi";

                    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                       ValidateAudience = true
                       
                    };
                });
//Policy "Apiscope" created 
services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("Apiscope", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("Scope", "api1");
                    
                });

            });

services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("AdminUsers", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireRole("admin");

                });

            });
```

**In controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "AdminUsers")]
        public IActionResult GetAdminMessage()
        {
            return Ok("Hello Admin");
        }
```

1. Is it possible access identity scope in .Net Core API? if yes, How to do?
2. To get the role value, do I need to add in APIScopes of "api1" userclaims as "address,role" **or** can do it by  above Q1 ?
3. In Policy "AdminUser", I am checking role by adding "api1" (APIScopes) userclaims as "address,role" but I could not access GetAdminMessage(). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it possible access identity scope in .Net Core API? if yes, How to do?*

The claims in the IdentityResources goes into the ID-Token. The content of the ID-Token is "converted" into the ClaimsPrincipal User object when you login in the client (AddOpenIDConnect). After that the ID-token is not used.

*To get the role value, do I need to add in APIScopes of "api1" userclaims as "address,role" or can do it by above Q1 ?*

APIScopes are on the API Side. API's receives Access-Tokens and it contains the user claism from the ApiSCopes and ApiResources. The claims in the access-token is converted into the user object in the API (using the AddJwtBearer) and you can use the AddPolicy system to authorize the user.

*In Policy "AdminUser", I am checking role by adding "api1" (APIScopes) userclaims as "address,role" but I could not access GetAdminMessage(). How to achieve this?*

ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer have different opinions on what the claim types (names) should be, so you need to tell AddJwtBearer what the real name is of your role claim, by using:

```
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        ...
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
```

You can also add this at the top of the ConfigureServicesmethod:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // By default, Microsoft has some legacy claim mapping that converts
    // standard JWT claims into proprietary ones. This removes those mappings.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

If that does not help ,you can also try add:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)
and [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: but its not working
`services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name;
                    //opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Scope;
` In access token role is existing
**"role": "admin",**

Comment: you write roles here opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";and you also write existing "role": "admin",  ? role or roles?

Comment: APIResource "testapi" has Scopes "api1" and userclaims as "role, name"  I have changed roleClaimType = role but not working. `Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                 .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", opt =>                 {                     opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";                     opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name;                     `

Comment: step #1 in troubleshooting this is to check what is actually inside the access token using jwt.io website.. step #2, is to check what claims are actually inside your ClaimPrincipal user object....  Feel free to post that to your question

Comment: In my prev comment I already mentioned that access token has **"role": "admin"**, (cheked using jwt.io) . How to check the objects in ClaimPrincipal user object. I am printing the user calims by `return Ok( new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value }));` getting the result as `{Type: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", Value: "admin"}`

Comment: Microsoft and OpenID-Connect have different opinion on what the claim names should be. Microsoft likes the URL format. See my updated answer.

Comment: Modified but not working. options.ClaimActions I am not getting `.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = "testapi";
                    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       RoleClaimType = "role",
                       NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name
                    };
                });`

Comment: You still see the http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" in the User object? you don't have any issue with casing? like role and Role? perhaps try to paste a copy of your access token and startup code and update your question?

Comment: You write [Authorize(Policy = "AdminUsers")]  but our policy is named  opt.AddPolicy("AdminUser"....      typo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231686/discussion-between-leo-and-tore-nestenius).

Comment: policy.RequireClaim("role","admin"); solved my issue. Thanks